# Rails Association has_many has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Добрый день,
помогите пожалуйста составить связи

есть модель `Order`

есть модель `User`

и промежуточная модель `OrderAndUser`

у `Order` должны быть:

```
1. Пользователи исполнители
2. Пользователи контролеры
3. Пользователи которым нужно отчитаться о выполнении
```

каждый `User` как бы это не логично звучало, может быть одновременно, одним из  исполнителей, одним из контролеров, одним из принимающим отчет

OrderAndUser

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: order_and_users
#
#  id       :integer          not null, primary key
#  order_id :integer
#  user_id  :integer
#  group    :string
#

class OrderAndUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :user
end
```

помогите сделать ассоциации для `User` и `Order`

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders_responsible # OrderAndUser через user_id и group с 'responsible'
  has_many :orders_monitoring # OrderAndUser через user_id и group с 'monitoring'
  has_many :orders_accept # OrderAndUser через user_id и group с 'accept'
end
```

Order

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_responsible # OrderAndUser через order_id и group с 'responsible'
  has_many :users_monitoring # OrderAndUser через order_id и group с 'monitoring'
  has_many :users_accept # OrderAndUser через order_id и group с 'accept'
end
```

Comment: поправил вопрос `@order.users_monitoring`  коллекция пользователей которые контролируют выполнение этого приказа, `@user.orders_monitoring` коллекция приказов в которых это юзер контролирует выполнение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ну, это типичный `has_many through`. Почти.

Как минимум вам нужна ассоциация-основа для него:

```
has_many :order_and_users # одинаковая и там и там
```

*(обратите внимание, как испортилось множественное число из-за названия модели, подумайте, нельзя ли переименовать эту модель во что-нибудь вроде "участие")*

И тогда можно ссылаться на всех прилинкованных таким образом пользователей:

```
has_many :users, through: :order_and_users # хотя эта ассоциация вам не нужна, наверное
```

Теперь вопрос в том, как отфильтровать эти записи по полю в `order_and_users`. Можно [передать `has_many` проц или лямбду](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Scopes), которая наложит дополнительный скоуп на ассоциацию.

Ситуация немножко осложняется тем, что явно инстансы от этой модели нигде не фигурируют. Но AcitveRecord всё равно будет делать `join` на эту таблицу, поэтому условие на поле в ней можно привинтить с помощью `merge` или явным указанием `таблица: { поле: значение }`. Но я предпочитаю первый способ, т. к. избавляет от необходимости точно знать название таблицы (конечно, всегда есть `OrderAndUser.table_name`, но это как-то совсем не очень).

Получится примерно так:

```
has_many :users_monitoring,
         -> { merge(OrderAndUser.where(group: 'monitoring')) },
         through: :order_and_users,
         source: :user # указание ассоциации-цели, OrderAndUser#user
                       # т. к. из users_monitoring догадаться о user AR не сможет
                       # было бы has_many :users, смогло бы
```

Остальные по аналогии.

---

**Можно сделать ещё смешнее**, но несколько *запутаннее*: сделать скоупы, аналогичные вышеупомянутой лямбде, в модуле, и включить их в `Order` и `User`:

```
scope :monitoring, -> { merge(OrderAndUser.where(group: 'monitoring')) }
```

А ассоциации сделать общие, без лямбд (вышеупомянутый "ненужный" пример).

```
has_many :users, through: :order_and_users
```

Тогда можно пользоваться весёлым синтаксисом вида:

```
@order.users.monitoring
@user.orders.monitoring
```

...только употребление этих скоупов вне означенной ассоциации будет приводить к неправильному SQL (ссылку на неупомянутую в `FROM` таблицу) и будет падать.

Comment: Спасибо большое, добавил правку к Вашему ответу

Comment: @МихаилЛуцко я её даже увидеть не успел, [её отклонили](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/122889) :) Но правка, вообще-то, в верном направлении (но не совсем верная), т. к. `users_monitoring` у `OrderAndUser` нет. А ещё я б на вашем месте поменял местами слова на `monitoring_users`, т. к. так чище единственное/множественное число, да и звучит лучше.